# performance counters and Hyper-V VM and Azure VM and windows server 2012

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, hyper-v, iis-8.5, perfmon

Ok so i have a web application that is setup on Azure VM (IIS). The performance counters will not report data on Azure VM, but they seem to report well on hyper-v vm. Both vm's are running windows server 2012 R2.

Do I need to open ports on Azure vm? at this point, I think its a permission/ports problem.

On hyper-v vm, I can run perfmon and add counters and I can see data being reported. I did the same on azure vm and saw no data being reported...

ideas?

Comment: Azure VMs are different with Hyper-V VMs, you should enable performance counters for a VM firstly. The data is stored in storage account table name is `WADPerformanceCountersTable`. Do you check it? You could use Azure Storage API to get information from it.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT, that approach can be used but it isnt the problem here, the performance monitor tool should still report counters when opened inside azure vm , just like in hyper- vm. something is blocking the counters either permissions or firewall/ports.

Answer (score 0):

I have test deployed a Windows Server 2012 R2 Azure VM with the default settings, with no additional port and permission set, and added performance counters as per my requirement and successfully got the reported generated. Refer the screenshot below for your reference. 
So, basically the exact same steps on Hyper-V should work on Azure VM as well. You just need to figure out/isolate the underlying issue with Windows, I presume it throws an error pointing out the cause. Please do let me know the exact error if any for further analysis.

[Perform on Azure VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGeqU.png)

Comment: it's a firewall/port issue with the said Azure vm instance running sql server. I have setup sql server on my local server as well as on hyper-v locally running windows server 2012. signalr had no issues sending peformance counter bindings to app insights.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, if the issue is still haven’t been fixed. As you have identified the issue to be related to port/firewall on the problematic VM, you may further narrow down the issue, try disabling the firewall service on the VM temporarily and then observe the flow. (Note: For security of the VM, re-enable it immediately or open appropriate ports). Also, if it is an ARM VM (not a Classic VM), try opening /creating appropriate NSG rules and then test it out. If feasible, try this on another Azure VM and let me know if you experience the same behavior.